# How div will show in the vertical coordinates 20px when I click on the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="#test">click</a>
```

and a div like this:

```
<div id="test">Hello world ...!</div>
```

when I click on that link, it shows me the `div` on the top of page `(scrollTop=0)`. Now I have a header (fixed) and the height of my header is 20px. So how is it possible that it shows me the `div` twenty-pixel lower when I click on the link?

---

**Edit:**

here is my url: `www.example.com/about#test`

Now I want to show *test div* in this position: `scrollTop(20)+"px"`

It should be noted that I have 10 div *(not just test div)*, anyway I need to a optimized approach. I think using of `$(#one)` , `$(#two)` , ... is not optimized .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the exact Scroll position of the element with:

```
var destination = $('#test').offset().top;
```

Then you won't have to worry about the height of the header if it changes

If you add jQuery UI you can do a nice animation to scroll to the element with something like this:

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: destination}, 600, "easeOutExpo", function(){});
```

Full Code:

```
$('a[href=#test]').on('click',function() {
     var destination = $('#test').offset().top;       
     $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: destination}, 1000, "easeOutExpo", function(){});
    return false;
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/5akh7va2/

Comment: And what to do with `destination`?

Comment: I tested it, and unfortunately does not works. can you give me a fiddle ?

Comment: how can I extend it for 10 div ?

Comment: as in you want to have 10 different links and 10 different scroll positions?

Comment: exactly ...! I need to copy-paste your code 10 time for each link ?